Does esbuild transform dependencies from node_modules?
I'm using esbuild via ruby on rails to build my js application.  My build command in dev looks like:
esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --target=es2018 --sourcemap --define:global=window --loader:.png=file --loader:.eot=dataurl --loader:.woff=dataurl --loader:.woff2=dataurl --loader:.ttf=dataurl --loader:.svg=dataurl --public-path=/asssets --asset-names=[name]-[hash].digested --outdir=app/assets/builds/

Specifically the --target=es2018 part, as I need to take advantage of esbuild transform functionality to convert many newer js expressions into es6/7 code.
However, the end result is still full of object/array destructuring, all from dependencies included via /node_modules.
Is there any way to configure esbuild to also transform these dependencies?
I've tried lots of configuration changes, mostly trying to manually disable certain features (like descructuring), as documented in https://esbuild.github.io/api/#supported.
esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --target=es2018 --supported:destructuring=false ...

However, this just results in the error:

Transforming destructuring to the configured target environment
("es2018" + 1 override) is not supported yet

And only in my own project code, which from what I could tell it was already transforming destructuring correctly before I configured it.

All of ES6, ES7 and ES2018 did include destructuring syntax, so it's unclear why you would expect the code to be converted. You'll need to target ES5 or older if you want to get rid of destructuring.

It looks like this was the problem: I think what I really did want was ES5 syntax, even though I thought ES6/7 would be appropriate here.  I eventually got esbuild-plugin-es5 configured and this produced code that worked for what I needed it to do.
